# Google Sheet REGEXEXTRACT extract text

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Given this value in A1:

```
https://www.rositarococo.com/?modeload=modeload-sigma-1&adsetname=cbo-LLA1apilados&adname=Default+name+-+Conversiones&placement=Facebook_Mobile_Feed
```

How to extract whats between "adsetname=" and "&adname" using REGEXEXTRACT. My lookbehind regex doesn't work in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "adsetname=(.+)&adname")
```

[image: 0]